# Conditional probability derivation with example

Tags: probability

the formula for conditional probability is

> $P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$

I am giving a simple problem to explain my doubt. *(this question is made by me to explain my doubt and may contain errors. if so, please correct me)*

> 2 blue and 3 red balls are in a bag. We take 2 balls without
>   replacement.
>
> Suppose A is the event that first ball is blue and B is the event that second ball is red
>
> P(B|A) = P(drawing a red ball when a blue ball is drawn) which is
>   $\dfrac{3}{4}$

The above answer is derived using basic conditional probability concepts. But, according to the formula of conditional probability given at the beginning, how do we solve it?

*Note:  The derivation given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Formal_derivation) for derivation of the formula is too difficult for me to understand. My text book does not give a proof for this. So, please explain in simple terms, if possible, using the same example*

Comment: In your example problem, what exactly is the question? Calculating $P(A \mid B)$?

Comment: Also, are we looking for the probability of getting a blue ball as the _second_ ball, given that the _first_ ball is red?

Comment: @DylanSp,  sorry, my question is how to calculate P(A∣B) using the formula $P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: or, let me put it in this way. $ P(A|B)=\dfrac{2}{4}$. $P(B)=\dfrac{3}{5}$ so, $P(A∩B)=\dfrac{3}{10}$. But, what exactly meant by $P(A∩B)=\dfrac{3}{10}$

Comment: Your problem is with the way you are defining the events A and B. The definitions should be "B is the event that the first ball is red" and "A is the event that the second ball is blue".

Comment: @user137481, edited my question as per your comment. Could you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events should be defined accurately. $2/4$ is the probability of "drawing a blue ball in the second attempt, given that in the first attempt you have drawn a red ball". So, order is important in this definition of the events.

Events can be defined as below:

A= drawing a blue in the second attempt

B= drawing a red in the first attempt

Using the concept of conditional probability, $P(A|B)=2/4$

Using the formula, $\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}=\frac{3*2/5*4}{3/5}=\frac{2}{4}$

The other way of defining would be:

A= having at least one blue after two attempts

B= having at least one red after two attempts

Using the concept of conditional probability, for this case, is a bit hard.

Using the formula, $\frac{P(A∩B)}{P(B)}=\frac{(3*2*2)/(5*4)}{((3*4*2)-6)/5*4}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: You are welcome. glad it was helpful.